# Is there a specific folder for notification icons?

Tags: icons

Is there a folder in `/usr/share/icon` which contains all the icons for the system tray? I'm not sure what size is used so I can't find it.

Comment: 1.Icons used in the notification bubbles are taken from `usr/share/icons/[icontheme]/apps/[size]`. 2.The indicator icons are in the status folder inside any of the installed icon themes.

Comment: what size are the status icons?

Comment: They use different sizes.